# Picard's Theorem for functions of integral order

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is entire and has order of growth $\rho \geq 1$ an integer, then if $f$ did not attain $\alpha \neq \beta$, we could write $f-\alpha = e^{P_1} $ and $f - \beta = e^{P_2}$ for $P_1$ and $P_2$ polynomials of degree $\rho$. Then we can differentiate to get that $P_1 = P_2$ and so we've proven Picard's Little Theorem in this case.

How can we show that the function $f$ must attain every complex value infinitely many times with at most one exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed just the same argument.
If $f$ did attain $\alpha \ne \beta $ only finitely many times, we could write $f-\alpha =Q_1 e^{P_1}$ and $f-\beta =Q_2e^{P_2}$, where $$
Q_1=\prod_{j=1}^n (z-a_j),\; Q_2=\prod_{j=1}^m (z-b_j)\quad (\text{interpret the product as $1$ if $n=0$ or $m=0$.})$$
with zeros $a_j$ of $f-\alpha $, zeros $b_j$ of $f-\beta ,$ since $(f-\alpha )/\prod (z-a_j)$ and $(f-\beta )/\prod (z-b_j)$ are zero-free entire functions with order of growth $\rho \ge 1$.

Then we can differentiate to get that $Q_1=cQ_2.$ This contradicts the assumption that $\alpha \ne \beta $. (If $Q_1=Q_2=1$, it reduces to the first problem.)